# Keeping attribute names simple when using getters and setters

Tags: python

Is the use of `_pn` in `__init__` pythonic? It seems that most examples change the actual attribute to `self._pn` to indicate it's private, but I would like to be able to call `self.pn` but have the advantage of checks with setters.

The following code will cause a recursive loop:

```
class part:
'Holds various attributes of interest for a part number'
def __init__(self, pn):
    self.pn = pn

def set_pn(self, pn):
    if type(pn) != str:
        raise Exception("Part number needs to be a string")
    self.pn = _pn

pn = property(fset = set_pn)
```

The following won't, but I'm not sure if `_pn` is pythonic:

```
class part:
'Holds various attributes of interest for a part number'
def __init__(self, _pn):
    self.pn = _pn

def set_pn(self, pn):
    if type(pn) != str:
        raise Exception("Part number needs to be a string")
    self.pn = _pn

_pn = property(fset = set_pn)
```

Comment: Please check your indentation.

Comment: What is the `part` class for? Is there anything else in the class, or does it exist solely to hold a part number property? As the question now stands, it's looking a little bit [hypothetical](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/9357).

Comment: It's going to a hold a lot of attributes related to manufacturing, and behaviors, such as lead time, lead time type, quality numbers etc. I simplified it for posting!

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226)

Comment: This looks like example code. Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the best way to do it:

```
class Part(object):
    def __init__(self, pn):
        self.pn = pn

    @property
    def pn(self):
        return self._pn

    @pn.setter
    def pn(self, value):
        if type(value) != str:
            raise Exception("Part number must be a string")
        self._pn = value
```

Remarks:

- The `_` prefix for properties is well-accepted, [see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)
- `self.pn = pn` is to reuse the validation implemented in the setter
- Class names should be `CamelCase`
- Modern classes should extend `object` (`class Part(object): ...` as opposed to plain `class Path: ...`)
- Doc strings should be `"""class description"""` instead of `'class description'`

Answer (score 0):

In general, the Python philosophy is EAFP, which means that it's...

> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many other languages such as C.\

(from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html))

This applies to getters and setters because, the Python way is really to avoid their use entirely (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/python-property-versus-getters-and-setters)). Python trusts programmers to do the right thing; encourages elegance through duck-typing rather than type-assertions; and favors exception handling to guard clauses.

As the provided links state, the Pythonic-way of doing this is to use properties (see links for more details).

If you're looking for more information on the `_...` and `__...` prefix notations, I'd highly recommend [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python).